# How to configure middleware in DI in Slim 3

Tags: php, slim

I want to configure several middleware in Dependency Container in Slim, so that I can set several constants in a same place and add middleware in a ease.

E.G.

```
$configuration = [
    'settings' => [
        'displayErrorDetails' => true,
    ],
    'auth_settings' => [
        'serect' => 'garyAPIserver',
    ],
];
$container = new Slim\Container($configuration);
$container['auth'] = function ($c) {
    return new AuthMiddleware($c['auth_settings']);
};
$app = new Slim\App($container);
```

And I try to invoke the middleware in DI:

```
$app->add($app->get('auth'));
```

And I got the warning message print by php:

> Warning: Missing argument 2 for Slim\App::get(), called in E:\www\slimServer-3.0\index.php on line 12 and defined in E:\www\slimServer-3.0\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\App.php on line 146

And the error message print by Slim:

```
Type: RuntimeException
Message: is not resolvable
File: E:\www\slimServer-3.0\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\CallableResolver.php
Line: 82
```

I am new in Slim, there it possible to set middleware in DI? Is there any guides with the similar scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using the `$container` variable:

```
$app->add($container->get('auth'));
```

Then you can use it in your router functions using:

```
$auth = $this->get('auth');
```

Take a look [here](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/concepts/di.html) for more information.